# memoir on TeX Live 2018 breaks figure numbering after \mainmatter

Tags: errors, numbering, memoir

I'm using memoir 3.7g, with lualatex under TeX Live 2018.

With the below example,

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{Demo}

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{This should be Figure 1.1.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the figure numbers (and tables) do not have a separator between chapter and figure number:

[image: demo: wrong figure numbering (no separator)]

Avoid using `\mainmatter`, and it's all fine:

[image: demo: correct figure numbering]

I know that somehow `\mainmatter` is eating the separator, so it can be patched back with something like:

```
\csletcs{@memoirmainmatter}{mainmatter}
\renewcommand*{\mainmatter}{
  \@memoirmainmatter
  \renewcommand*\thefigure{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure}
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, do you have a better way to solve it?

Comment: I think this is a bug introduced into the LaTeX kernel which should be fixed soon.  Try the solution here [Dot between chapter number and figure number disapear after update](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/427451). If it works, then we can close this as a duplicate. (I haven't installed TL 2018 yet, so I can't test).

Comment: It is caused by a latex kernel bug, counterwithin (used inside mainmatter) has been moved to the latex kernel, sadly it was not implemented wrong. An update should (to the latex kernel) should be in its way